# Empty struct or anonymous struct as tag

Tags: c++, c++11, tags, c++14

Is there any difference in a use between defining the tag type as an anonymous empty struct or as an empty struct?

```
using A = struct {};
struct B {};
```

At my mind the only difference is the "effective" type name, when one utilize a kind of reflection (i.e. `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, `<cxxabi.h>:abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid().name())` etc).

ADL work for both ways:

```
namespace ns
{

using A = struct {};
struct B {};

constexpr
bool
adl(A)
{
    return true;
}

constexpr
bool
adl(B)
{
    return true;
}

}

template< typename type >
constexpr
bool
adl(type)
{
    return false;
}

static_assert(adl(ns::A{}));
static_assert(adl(ns::B{}));
```

Comment: Well, `using` is pretty much `typedef`, which traces back to C's `typedef struct`. I don't see why those should differ in any way.

Comment: You can't write any special member functions for an anonymous structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the different strings you've already noted, the only significant difference is that you can refer to `B` using an *elaborated-type-specifier*, so you can say `struct B b;` instead of `B b;` but you cannot use `struct A a;` because `A` is a typedef-name not a class-name.

However there is almost never a good reason to say `struct B` instead of just `B` so in practice the difference is not important, especially not for tag types.

Comment: About the only time I've needed to preface the word "struct" is for the Linux *stat() calls, which take a pointer to struct stat as one of their parameters.

Comment: @Nevin, yes, me too. That name-clash was frequently annoying while implementing the Filesystem TS :-\